# Select multiple and single data filter php Undefined variable: product,supplier

Tags: php

I have 3 selected data Groups, supplier and product; and I want to filter by either one or two or three selected data together.

I used this method to filter, but it doesn't work:

This's my code:

```
$sec_query = "";
$group= $_GET['group']; 
$supplier = $_GET['supplier']; 
$product= $_GET['product'];

if(isset($_GET['supplier']) && !empty( $_GET['supplier'])){
    $sec_query = " AND catalog.supplier = '$supplier' "; 
}
if(isset($_GET['product']) && !empty($_GET['product'])){
    $sec_query = " AND catalog.product = '$product' "; 
}
if (isset($_GET['group']) && !empty($_GET['group'])){
    $sec_query = " AND catalog.group = '$group' ";     
}

$sql = " SELECT group,id,product,supplier,SUM(total)as total,date_created FROM catalog WHERE 1=1 $sec_query AND date_created > '2014' GROUP BY group,id,product,supplier,date_created ORDER BY id";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$data_sql = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


<form role="form" action='' method='GET'>
    <select name="group" id = "group" style="width: 100%;">
        <option value="group1" <? if($group== "group1" ){ echo "SELECTED = selected";} ?> >Group1</option>
        <option value="group2" <? if($group== "group2" ){ echo "SELECTED = selected";} ?> >Group2</option>
        <option value="group3" <? if($group== "group3" ){ echo "SELECTED = selected";} ?> >Group3</option>
    </select>
    <select name = "supplier" style="width: 100%;">
        <option selected="selected">
        <?php $sql_supplier = "SELECT supplier FROM  catalog GROUP BY supplier";
        $query_supplier = $conn->prepare($sql_supplier); 
        $query_supplier->execute();
        $data_supp = $query_supplier->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($data_supp as $data => $s):?>
        </option>
        <option value="<?php echo($s['supplier']); ?>"><?php echo($s['supplier']); ?></option>
        <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
        </select>
        <select name = "product" style="width: 100%;">
            <option selected="selected">
            <?php $sql_product = "SELECT product FROM  catalog GROUP BY product";
            $query_product = $conn->prepare($sql_product); 
            $query_product->execute();
            $data_product = $query_product->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($data_product as $data => $p):
            ?>
            </option>
            <option value="<?php echo($p['product']); ?>"><?php echo($p['product']); ?></option>
            <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>
           </select>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: can you post your final query

Comment: Please provide some more information, how does it not work: What error are you getting?

Comment: What doesn't work? Which errors are you getting, and what is the final query it is trying to execute?

Comment: I added what im getting like error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea how to make it.

```
if(isset($_GET['supplier']) && !empty( $_GET['supplier'])){
    $sec_query = " AND supplier = '$supplier' ";
} 
if(isset($_GET['product']) && !empty($_GET['product'])){
    $sec_query = " AND product= '$product' ";
}
if (isset($_GET['group']) && !empty($_GET['group'])){
    $sec_query = " AND group = '$group' "; 
}

$sql = " SELECT  group,id,product,supplier,SUM(total) as total,date_created FROM catalog WHERE 1=1 $sec_query AND date_created > '2014' GROUP BY group,id,product,supplier,date_created ORDER BY id";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I used your method but I still have the same problem. "Undefined index: group,product,supplier"

Comment: Try removing them and add them one by one until you get a error

Comment: i declare the variable $sec_query = " "; but i have always this same error Undefined index : group

Comment: offcourse.. You need to define first the $sec_query. So at the begging of your php code you must assign an emty value to $sec_query. like this $sec_query = "";

Comment: yes I have already made it. but i have always the same error Notice: Undefined index: group in Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean  $group= $_GET['group'];

Comment: echo $group. and tell us what's you get. Have you post all your code?

Comment: Try to use unique variables. u are using $sql 3 times. Keep only one and change the other ones.

Comment: You are executing the $sql 3 times. $query = $conn->prepare($sql); You must change it to this $query = $conn->prepare($sql); and $query = $conn->prepare($sql_product); and $query = $conn->prepare($sql_supplier);    olso update once more your code to the latest changes

Comment: I update all changes, the same error undefined index group

Comment: I delete " $group = $_GET['group']; "  and now i have this error Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Comment: i just edit your code please review it and let me know

Comment: Thanks,when I select the group and the product it recovered the data in url like that "cacatalog_list.php?group=group1&supplier=&product=product1&submit= "  but not on the table by displaying this error Undefined variable: product.

Comment: add this 3 lines at the top. $supplier = $_GET['supplier'];
$product = $_GET['product'];
$group = $_GET['group'];

Comment: before filtering it shows me a table with all data and errors Undefined variable: product Undefined variable: supplier against when I filter it works.

Comment: ok replace the code with this.  @$supplier = $_GET['supplier']; @$product = $_GET['product']; @$group = $_GET['group'];

Comment: It works but against in the beginning it gives me all the data since 2014 and it's really slow you have any idea how I can recover in 2016 just before filtering

Comment: before filtering i want to return data of year now and month now

Comment: use date functions. $year = date('Y'); $month = date('m');

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['group']) && !empty($_GET['group']))

 {

   $group = "AND catalog.group = '$group' "; 

 }
```

Why are you using catalog.group='$group';

i think it should be catalog.group=$_GET['group'];

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$condition = "";
$condition = $supplier.$product.$group."AND date_created > '2014'" ;
$condition = ltrim($condition,"AND");

 $sql = " SELECT group,id,product,supplier,SUM(total)as total,
         date_created FROM catalog WHERE ".$condition ." GROUP BY group,id,product,supplier,date_created ORDER BY id";
```

i hope it will be helpful